# UITableView editing animation duration

Tags: ios, uikit, tableview, uiviewanimation, uitableview

Does any one know how long the animation

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

in the `UITableViewCell` takes? I´m testing with 0.5 seconds but i´d rather like to use a constant from the Framework somthing like `UITableViewCellEditingAnimationDuration`

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 10):

In version 4.3.5 is 0.3 seconds

Comment: How did you find out? Is there any constant which can be used? I have the same problem and I don't want to update my app every time Apple changes the animation Duration of some things.
thx in advance.
Mav

Comment: I think apple won't change it. I did some tests and 0.3 was the better duration for animations I found.

Answer (score 4):

From UIView.h

```
+ (void)setAnimationDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;              // default = 0.2
```

and I found 0.2 s indeed seemed to match things pretty well.

Comment: The same comment is there in the iOS 9.2 SDK, by the way.